# Update ListView on other ListView's SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a `ListView` with items and when user clicks on an item, I want in other `ListView` to appear a list of other items, and those other items depend on first `ListView`'s selected item's ID.
I have a ServiceManager class, which recieves objects from server asynchronously and passes them to DataManager class, which requires objects via ServiceManager when necessary and stores those objects.
Usually I would bind those objects in XAML like this: `ItemsSource="Binding Instance.MyObjects, Source={StaticResource DataManager}"`, but this time I have to pass that ID as parameter to ServiceManager method.
So how do I update second `ListView` on first `ListView`'s `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: I do it this way, bind both list views to two CollectionViewSource one for each listview, set up a SelectionChanged evenhandler in first listview, when it fires add a invoke a filter (description) to 2nd list view.  Works like a charm everytime!  And it's fast...

Comment: @JohnPeters I don't fully understand your solution. Could you please provide some simple code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create *CurrentItem* property in *ServiceManager*:

```
    public MyItemType CurrentItem 
    {
       get {
          return _CurrentItem; 
       }
       set { 
          _CurrentItem = value; 
          if(_CurrentItem != null)
             MyObjects = LoadMyObjects(_CurrentItem.ID);
          else
             MyObjects = null;
       }
    }
```

In *CurrentItem* property setter load data for second ListView. Bind *CurrentItem* property of the first ListView:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataManager.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataManager.CurrentItem}" />
```

In this way when *SelectedItem* of the first ListView is changed the property setter of *CurrentItem* property is called and MyObjects is updating. (You should implement [INotifyPropertChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for *ServiceManager* and call *PropertyChnaged* in *MyObjects* property setter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Binding _CurrentItem_ to first ListView isn't really working, but I asign it in code behind on SelectionChanged event, and now it is working.

Comment: OK. May be binding in XAML not working because I don't know how exactly to write it in you case. It depends on your DataManager implementation and XAML source. May be it's possible set binding in this way: `SelectedItem={Binding Path=CurrentItem, Source={StaticResource DataManager}, Mode=TwoWay}`

Comment: I tried _TwoWay_ Mode as well, but it wasn't working. I'm not sure if it is good practice, but in my SelectionChanged event I set `DataManager.CurrentItem = MyList.SelectedItem` and it's working.